# Change static array to dynamic array in class

Tags: c++

The code is supposed to read lines from a text file, where each line is an object of Class1, and put them in a list of Class2 object. I'm trying to change all static arrays to dynamic, but with no luck.

The program includes two classes. Class1 include attributes like date, name etc. Class2 is an list of class1 objects. I have not included all methods of the program. The Class1 objects are correctly formed from reading the file.

The problem appears when I'm trying to copy objects from class1 into the dynamic attribute receipt in Class2.

Testing shows that program stops at "rece[amountr- 1] = R;". Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.

```
class receipt // 1
 {
  private:
      string date;
      string name;
      int amount;
      string *friends;

  public:
      receipt();
      ~receipt();
      receipt& operator=( const receipt& R);
      bool readreceipt( istream &is );
};

class receiptlist     // 2
 {
  private:
      int amountr;
      receipt *rece;

  public:
      receiptlist();
      ~receiptlist();
      void resize ( int n );
      void readin ( istream & is );
      void addOne( receipt & R );
};

Main:
receiptlist RL;
ifstream is( "supermarkadoreceipts.txt" );
RL.readin (is)


Constructor:
receiptlist::receiptlist()
{
    amountr = 0;
    rece = new receipt [amountr ];
    receipt *rece = 0;
}

receipt & receipt::operator=( const receipt & R)
{
  if (this != &R)
    {
      delete[] friends;
      date = R.date ;
      name = R.name;
      amount = R.amount;
      friends = new string[amount];
      for (int i=0; i < amount; i++)
        friends [i] = R.friends [i];
    }
  return *this;
}

Methods:
void receiptlist::readin ( istream & is )
{
    receipt *rece = 0;

    receipt  R;

    while (R.readreceipt(is))
    {
        addOne(R);
    }
}

void receiptlist::addOne( receipt  & R ) 
{
    resize(amountr+ 1);
    rece[amountr- 1] = R;
}

void receiptlist::resize( int n )
{
    receipt *p = 0;

    if ( n > 0 )
    {
      p = new receipt[n];

      int i
      for (i = 0; i < n && i < amountr; i++ )
      {
          p[i] = rece[i];
      }

    }
    delete [] rece;
    rece = p;
    amountr = n;
}
```

The program compiles but gives a pointer error, which I cannot solve.

Comment: Your code only shows definitions. There is no code to inspect. The bug(s) is somewhere in your memory management

Comment: If `string *friends;` is the array in quest (actually it's a pointer) then `std::vector<std::string> friends;` might be the solution you're looking for. (Similar for `receipt *rece;`.)

Comment: After your edit, I warmly recommend: Throw all this `new` fiddling away and switch to `std::vector<>`. It provides all out of the box you're fighting with without the need of any pointer or `new` (or `delete`).

Comment: What's the purpose of the two "receipt *rece = 0;" lines (in constructor and readin function)? Does nothing that I can see.

Comment: Your `receiptlist::resize()` doesn't look that bad (but I debugged by eyes). The `receiptlist::addOne()` as well. Your constructor `receiptlist::receiptlist()` is strange. I would recommend `receiptlist::receiptlist(): amountr(0), rece(nullptr) { }` (initialization instead of assignments).

Comment: Can we see the code for your constructor and assignment operator for class "receipt". If it's the assignment that's causing the crash, then that's a good place to start looking!

Comment: The copy constructor of `receipt` is not overloaded. Please, have a look on the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). It might be an issue when passing instances of `receipt` by value (e.g. in function call).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and sorry for my lack of memory understanding ( im new and trying to learn)! Im trying to bypass vectors in this code and i have also included a operator constructor in Class1 that should work in this case.

Comment: What is your "Transaktion" class? You define "addOne(Transaktion & T)" but call addOne with a receipt &R.

Comment: "Im trying to bypass vectors in this code..."  That's not a good idea.  If you are learning C++, you should start with `std::vector` as your go-to container.  You should not need or be using `new` in modern C++ (at least until you get into advanced C++).